# Why I need to use ref keyword in both declaration and Call?

Tags: c#, keyword, ref

Duplicate of: [What is the purpose of the “out” keyword at the caller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393946/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-out-keyword-at-the-caller-in-c/1393956#1393956)

**Why** I need to use **'ref'** keyword in both declaration and Call.

```
void foo(ref int i)
{

}
```

For example, Consider above function. If I will call it without ref keyword as

```
foo(k);
```

it will give me error :

> Argument '1' must be passed with the
>   'ref' keyword

**Why** isn't it enough to just specify in the method signature only ?

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate. Finding it now...

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I have tried to search but could not find it. I will close it if it is duplicate.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : Thanks... That thread has more information. Voted to close.

Comment: It wasn't me that added the reference - but that was the question I was thinking of :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because `ref` indicates that the parameter should be passed in by reference. It is something like pointer in C++

For example;

```
void CalFoo()
{
  var i=10;
  foo(ref i);  //i=11
}
void foo(ref int i)
{
   i++;
}
```

but

```
void CalFoo()
{
  var i=10;
  foo(i);  //i=10
}
void foo(int i)
{
   i++;
}
```

I think you can have both `foo(ref int)` and `foo(int)` in one single class. So if you don't specify the `ref`.. how does the compiler knows which one to call?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui : Ya I agree with that. But my question is why I need to use it in both Method call and declaration.

Comment: Ngu Soon Hui : Great thanks.. Now I understand why.. Will wait for few more answers... otherwise you rock.... +1

Comment: Because they `int` and `ref int` are different types, also for overloading. See the last sentence in this answer. If you would allow dropping the `ref` then your method call would have a different signature than the invoked method. Surely solvable, unless overloading strikes. But it could lead to all sorts of subtle bugs. Also you know explicitly that the method *can change* the object reference when calling methods with `ref`.

Comment: I wouldn't bring up the overloading issue at all for this question... The compiler for .NET does some very complex overloading resolving behind the scenes (especially now with the introduction of the `dynamic` type) and has errors for ambiguous cases. What's much more important with using the `ref` keyword is to explicitly show that the value might change in the method call.

Comment: @Johannes: They are not different types, you can't overload a method with only a ref or 'normal' type: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(VS.80).aspx , second code sample

Comment: No, you cannot have both in one class. Overloads which differ only by ref/out are not allowed. That's because int and ref int is in fact the same type, just using a different parameter passing convention.

Comment: You can have signatures `int` and `ref int` or `int` and `out int`, but you cannot have signatures `ref int` and `out int`.

Answer (score 9):

It enhances readability/understandability: When you look at the method call, you know that the ref value might change.

Comment: @Lennaert : Sounds like a valid argument. Can you point me to some manual stating this, if you have?

Comment: Actually, I can't find anything about it, but the compiler is smart enough to infer that it should pass a ref type (I assume), that's how I came to the conclusion. Maybe I stated it a bit too confidently :)

Comment: This is surely the answer: it's obvious that C#'s designers did not have to require 'ref' at the call site (almost no other languages require it), so why else would it be required but to make code more clear? (okay, it's also for overloading as Jon Skeet points out, but that's very rarely done since other .NET languages can't overload that way)

Answer (score 4):

(As mentioned, this is a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393946).)

For one thing, it's used as part of method overloading:

```
public void Foo(string x) { ... }
public void Foo(ref string x) { ... }

...

string x = "";
Foo(x); // Which should be used if you didn't have to specify ref?
```

Now one answer could be to prohibit that sort of overloading... but I think it's a good thing for C# to require this at the caller's side as documentation:

- The behaviour changes significantly when you use `ref` (or `out`)
- By calling out the rare uses of ref/out, it means you never need to *check* whether
  the argument is being passed by value or reference
- It also affects what you can pass (e.g. you can't pass a literal, or the result of a method call). This is clearer when it's explicit.

Note that C# 4 does allow implicit use of `ref` for COM methods as there are so many `ref` parameters which don't *really* have `ref` behaviour (or at least, they don't take advantage of it). In such cases the compiler introduces a new local variable so that from the caller's point of view the argument really *is* being passed by value:

```
ComMethod(x);
```

translates into:

```
MyType tmp = x;
ComMethod (ref tmp);
```

This is a good compromise for COM methods, but I'm glad it's not the case for normal managed code.

Comment: You are right Jon.. It is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393946/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-out-keyword-at-the-caller-in-c/1393956#1393956.

I have also voted to close it. Btw , You have also answered that question. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon : Btw, I had this question after reading your this ( http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html ) article.

Comment: @Mahin: Good feedback - if I remember, I'll try to add a section to that article.

Answer (score 3):

As the Method and the Caller may be "far" away from each other (Different Assemblies, you may not even have the source of the one containing the method), having to specify out and ref explicitly helps making the intent clear. So it's something for the user so that they really know what they do, not a technical necessity.

Answer (score 3):

While `ref` could most of the time be inferred from the method signature, it's always obligatory due to the fact that it can change the behavior of the code after the method call completely. Consider:

```
string hello = "world";
MyMethod(ref hello);
Console.WriteLine(hello);
```

If the `ref` keyword hadn't been there you would always expect the code to print out "world", while in reality, it can print anything.

Answer (score 1):

I have also heard (or read somewhere - myaybe it was in an interview with the language designers) that the reason (like for many other "features" in C#) is to remind the programmer that the function he is giong to call use the argument by reference.