# Is there a technical reason for requiring the "out" and "ref" keywords at the caller?

Tags: c#

When calling a method with a `ref` or `out` parameter, you have to specify the appropriate keyword when you call the method. I understand that from a style and code quality standpoint (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393958/1118660) for example), but I'm curious whether there is also a technical need for the keywords to be specified in the caller.

For example:

```
static void Main()
{
    int y = 0;
    Increment(ref y); // Is there any technical reason to include ref here?
}

static void Increment(ref int x)
{
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're asking whether the language could have been designed so that those aren't needed at the call site, the answer is yes. There is no particular reason they could not have been left out. The compiler has all the information it needs from the metadata, so it could make the proper transformation.

That said, doing so would have made it impossible to have these two overloads:

```
public void DoSomething(int x);
public void DoSomething(ref int x);
```

The compiler wouldn't be able to disambiguate that.

Although the `ref` and `out` could have been made optional, in which case those overloads would be allowed. And the compiler could either take the default (i.e. the non-ref), or issue an ambiguity error and make you specify which one you really wanted.

All that said, I *like* having to specify `ref` and `out` at the call site. It tells me that the parameter could potentially be modified. Having worked in Pascal for many years, where a `var` parameter is passed the same way that a value parameter is passed (the syntax at the call site is the same), I much prefer the specificity of C# in that regard.

Comment: Thanks Jim. That's exactly what I'm asking. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't something I was missing. As for the overload resolution, I'm not sure that disallowing that overload would be a bad thing!

Comment: Should probably mention that you cannot overload `DoSomething(ref int x)` with `DoSomething(out int x)` or vice versa.

Answer (score 12):

The only technical reason I could think of is overload resolution: you could have

```
static void Increment(ref int x)
```

and also

```
static void Increment(int x)
```

[This is allowed](http://ideone.com/uo45p2); without `ref` in the call, the compiler wouldn't be able to tell them apart.

Comment: I was literally seconds away from posting this myself.

Comment: True enough, but can you provide an example where that overload is actually sane? I can't come up with one.

Comment: @JasonWatkins I can come up with a semi-sane one, when you make a communication library that could post a new value to the server in "post and forget" mode, or posts a new value, waits for a response, and writes the returned value back to the `ref` parameter. Personally, I would give the two different names, but since the semantics of the two are close enough, I could buy an argument that an overload is warranted.

Comment: @JasonWatkins: The language team doesn't care your "business scene". They considered ref/out keyword part of the method's signature, that's why you need it in the caller.

Answer (score 9):

Another reason to require the modifier is to make changing a parameter to a `ref` or `out` a *breaking change*.  If the `ref`/`out` could be inferred, then an evil programmer changing a parameter from by-value to by-reference would not be detected by clients compiling against the new signature.  If a client called the method

```
public int Increment(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
```

by using

```
int result = Increment(x);
```

Suppose an evil developer decided to change the implementation to instead change the value passed by reference and return an *error code* if, say, the increment resulted in an overflow:

```
public int Increment(ref int x)
{
    x = x + 1;
    if(x == int.MinValue)  // overflow
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
}
```

Then a client building against the signature *would not receive a compile error*, but it would almost certainly break the calling app.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler needs to know the method parameters it is interpreting when it is building IL. 
One reason is having overloads like:

```
public void (ref int x) {}
public void (int x)     {}
```

Another reason is `out` will explicitly allow you to use pass-by-value parameter use the interpreted value outside the method. `ref` will give the pointer to the parameter thereby pointing any new value from the method to the same memory location